# RFC2616 algorithm for default content using Accept-Language header

Tags: internationalization, w3c

I'm designing a web service that has content stored in a database, and I want to ensure that the design is compliant with [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).  However, I'm a little unclear on the correct way to match content.

If I specify the behaviour as a user story:

```
Given I request content in 'en_GB'
When the server has content in 'en_US' 
     and the server has content in 'en_CA'
     and the server does not have content in 'en'
Then the server should return content in '???'
```

**Question**: what language should the server return the content in?

---

**Update**: Based on pawel-dyda's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098798/1033422), I believe the stories should look like this:

```
Given I request content in 'en_GB'
When the server has content in 'en_US' 
     and the server has content in 'en_CA'
     and the server has content in 'en'
Then the server should return content in 'en'

Given I request content in 'en_GB'
When the server has content in 'en_US' 
     and the server has content in 'en_CA'
     and the server does not have content in 'en'
Then the server should return content in the server default language
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a Locale fallback. For HTTP Accept-Language header I18n best practice rules are:

1. Given lang-country pair return the contents if it is available
2. Then try to return the content for given language, if it is available
3. Then try the next language on the list (start from 1)
4. If nothing works so far, return (application | server) default language.

For example, assuming your application contains German translation (de) and HTTP Accept-Language header looks like:

> Accept-Language: fr-FR, de-AT;q=0.7

The language returned should be German (de).

Going back to your question, what you should return is your default Locale. And obviously it is good to have common resources for given language (en in this case).